# Add a filter inside an action init

Tags: filters, actions, init

Hello in the `init` action, I would like to add a filter to a fairly large function to modify variables in the `$vars` array, for example the Wordpress post ID.

That is to say:

```php
    add_action( 'init',function(){
        //code
    
        add_filter( 'query_vars',function($vars){
            $vars[] = array('ID' => $myid);
             return $vars;
    
        });
    });
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: I am doing A/B/C tests of pages and with the same url I want to show a page with another ID, (i.e. edit the ID of the current post to display the complete content of another post).

Comment: This is a perfect example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)- you are asking about what you think the solution is rather than stating what the problem is that you are trying to solve. Yes, you can add a filter inside `init`, but this approach to your problem is completely wrong. Your comment below "I am doing A/B/C tests of pages and with the same url I want to show a page or another ID" should be your question.

Comment: @Milo You're absolutely right, but I've tried and I have not been able to edit the post ID. Right now I'm using a very bad option that is using file_get_content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To alter the page ID before the query is run, hook the [`request`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request) filter.

If you're using pretty permalinks, `pagename` will be set, you can overwrite `pagename` with another page slug:

```
function wpd_265903_request( $request ) {
    if( isset( $request['pagename'] ) ){ // any page
        $request['pagename'] = 'some-other-slug';
    }
    return $request;
}
add_filter('request', 'wpd_265903_request');
```

or you can unset pagename and set `page_id`:

```
function wpd_265903_request( $request ) {
    if( isset( $request['pagename'] ) ){
        unset( $request['pagename'] );
        $request['page_id'] = 106;
    }
    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpd_265903_request' );
```

Comment: thanks thanks, work perfectly, Sorry I can not give you points.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do something like that. And in fact, if you want to remove actions/filters, then you will be almost certainly be required to use one hook to remove it.

For instance, plugins load before the theme. So if a theme adds a hook to the `init` hook from the functions.php file like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_265903_init' );
```

Plugins would not be able to remove that action until after the theme gets setup:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {
  remove_action( 'init', 'wpse_265903_init' );
} );
```

Similarly, if you want some hooks to run only after the `admin_init` hook, then you can do something like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
  add_action( 'the_post', function() {
    do_something();
  } );
} );
```

The `init` hook fires on every request though, so I'm not sure the purpose of adding hooks from that particular hook.

Comment: I understand perfectly, and apologize if you do not explain to me well, I am doing a  A/B/C tests of pages and with the same url I want to show a page with another ID, and now I am testing several filters and action and I can not do it.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. Not the one that I was magically supposed to know that you wanted answered.